# Expand text field when text gets close to the end

Tags: jquery

I want to make the textfield expand when the text nearly gets to the end, it works but when i type the first letter in it shrinks and then it expands

i.e http://jsfiddle.net/Y3rMM/

How can i keep the textfield the same size until it reaches the end and expands

i.e so when i type my first letter it does not shrink but it stays the same size

```
//HTML
<input type="text"/>


//JQUERY
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("input").keyup(function(){
                    contents = $(this).val();
                    charlength = contents.length;
                    newwidth = 10 + (charlength*10);
                    $(this).css({width:newwidth});
                });        
            });
```

Comment: Making this plugin by own is bit difficult work. you can use any readymade available plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this plugin: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/

```
$('textarea#comment').autoResize({
    // On resize:
    onResize : function() {
        $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
    },
    // After resize:
    animateCallback : function() {
        $(this).css({opacity:1});
    },
    // Quite slow animation:
    animateDuration : 300,
    // More extra space:
    extraSpace : 40
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin :
http://www.technoreply.com/autogrow-textarea-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea.expand').keypress(function () {
    if ((this.rows * this.cols) <= this.value.length) 
        $(this).animate({ height: "4em" }, 500); 
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3rMM/334/)

Comment: will this work for a textfield as well so the length expands and not the the height @gdoron

Comment: @ShamariCampbell. I'm sorry, I couldn't understand your English.

Answer (score 0):

Craig Buckler's TextAreaExpander plugin for jQuery works fine. You can test it [here](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/demo.html)

Just attach the plugin to the textarea you want to expand;

```
$("textarea").TextAreaExpander();
```